# Checking if Xpath Exists

Tags: python, html, selenium, xpath, beautifulsoup

I'm currently using selenium, bs4 and python for scraping however I ran into a problem with regards to checking the Xpath if it exists or not, here's my code:

```
def hasXpath(xpath):
    try:
        browser.get(quote_page) 
        self.browser.find_element_by_xpath(xpath)
        return True
    except:
        return False                          

# IF PRICELIST EXISTS CONDITION/    

if hasXpath("(//div[@id='product-header h4']//span)[last()-2]") or hasXpath("(//div[@id='product-header']//span)[last()-1]") or hasXpath("(//div[@id='product-header']//span)[last()]"):
    #No. of Items Per Retail(NEED LOGIN)
    somthing = browser.find_element_by_xpath("(//div[@id='product-header']//td)[21]").get_attribute("innerText")
    print(somthing)

    #Retail Price(NEED LOGIN)
    browser.get(quote_page)
    somthing1 = browser.find_element_by_xpath("(//div[@id='product-header']//span)[last()]").get_attribute("innerText")
    print(somthing1)


    if hasXpath("(//div[@id='product-header']//span)[last()-1]"):

       #1No. of Items Per Retail(NEED LOGIN)
       something = browser.find_element_by_xpath("(//div[@id='product-header']//td)[19]").get_attribute("innerText")
       print(something)

       #1Retail Price(NEED LOGIN)
       browser.get(quote_page) 
       something = browser.find_element_by_xpath("(//div[@id='product-header']//span)[last()-1]").get_attribute("innerText")
       print(something1)
else:
  print("It didn't go inside")
```

As you can see it has a simple function `hasXpath()` where I pass the xpaths for the condition in the IF statement below it. However when I test it, everything seems to be going to the else statement. I also tried doubling the True condition but no luck. What did I do wrong when implementing this?

Comment: Add a [mcve] that includes a reduced copy of the markup for which your XPath is failing.  Without that, your question is incomplete.

Comment: Fundamentally the idea of `checking the Xpath if it exists or not` is vague. Perhaps users writes _xpath_ to locate elements. At-most you can check for an element (identified by a xpath) is **stale** or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## The problem

You appear to be using a variable that doesn't exist: `self`. (At least, there's nothing about your code snippet that indicates either that it might exist or that these might be instance methods.)

If you remove the wrapping `try: ... except: ...`, I bet you'll see the following error:

```
NameError: name 'self' is not defined
```

## The solution

Assuming `browser` is defined, just remove the `self.`.

## Bonus 1: Better exception handling

In general, you should:

- be as narrow as possible in what you expect to fail (what is included in the `try:` block) and
- be as specific as possible in what exceptions you handle.

In your case, it looks like you only want to guard the `find_element_by_xpath()` and only want to capture Selenium's `NoSuchElementException`:

```py
browser.get(quote_page)
try:
    browser.find_element_by_xpath(xpath)
    return True
except NoSuchElementException:
    return False
```

This specificity would have allowed the `NameError` caused by the use of `self` to bubble up to where you might see it, saving you the trouble of posting your question here.

## Bonus 2: More efficient page loading

You're calling `browser.get(quote_page)` as many as six times: twice in the body of your script; and once in the `hasXpath` function, which is called four times.

Since you're always loading the same page, just do it once at the start of your script.